# Scrolling Frames for iPad

Tags: ipad, iframe, scroll, telerik, rad-controls

I am developing a web application that is going to be both IE9/HTML5 compatible and work on the iPad.  The issue I'm running into is that I can't seem to get frames to scroll correctly (or at all) on the iPad while it works fine in a browser.  I have tried both single finger scrolling and two-finger scrolling and all of the listed combinations below.  Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

(FYI: Telerik is a third party control library)

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="radSplitter2" runat="server" Height="100%">
  <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane2" runat="server" Scrolling="Both">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" src="HTMLPage1.htm" />
  </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

---

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="radSplitter3" runat="server" Height="100%">
  <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane4" runat="server" Scrolling="Both" ContentUrl="HTMLPage1.htm">
  </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

---

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="radSplitter4" runat="server" Height="100%">
  <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane5" runat="server" Scrolling="Both">
    <div style="width:100%; overflow:auto">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" src="HTMLPage1.htm" />
    </div>
  </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

This code works but I really need to be able to include a page as a frame.

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="radSplitter1" runat="server" Height="100%">
  <telerik:RadPane ID="RadPane3" runat="server" Scrolling="Both">
    This Section Scrolls
    This Section Scrolls
    This Section Scrolls
    This Section Scrolls
    This Section Scrolls
    This Section Scrolls
  </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being just forcing the frames to scroll using javascript:

just put this in place of your  tag.

```
    <div id="scrollDiv" runat="server" style="position:relative; overflow:auto"></div>
    <iframe id="iFrame1" runat="server" style="display:none"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function initMobileScroll_<%= this.ClientID %>(ele) {
            var mobileScrollArea = document.getElementById(ele);

            mobileScrollArea.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
                touchstart_<%= this.ClientID %>(event);
            });

            mobileScrollArea.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event) {
                touchmove_<%= this.ClientID %>(event);
            });

            // let’s set the starting point when someone first touches
            function touchstart_<%= this.ClientID %>(e) {
                startY = e.touches[0].pageY;
                startX = e.touches[0].pageX;
            }

            // calls repeatedly while the user’s finger is moving
            function touchmove_<%= this.ClientID %>(e) {
                var touches = e.touches[0];

                // override the touch event’s normal functionality
                e.preventDefault();

                // y-axis
                var touchMovedY = startY - touches.pageY;
                startY = touches.pageY; // reset startY for the next call
                mobileScrollArea.scrollTop = mobileScrollArea.scrollTop + touchMovedY;

                // x-axis
                var touchMovedX = startX - touches.pageX;
                startX = touches.pageX; // reset startX for the next call
                mobileScrollArea.scrollLeft = mobileScrollArea.scrollLeft + touchMovedX;
            }

        }

        var theFrame_<%= this.ClientID %> = document.getElementById('<%= iFrame1.ClientID %>');
        theFrame_<%= this.ClientID %>.onload = function () {
            var frameBody = theFrame_<%= this.ClientID %>.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            document.getElementById('<%= scrollDiv.ClientID %>').innerHTML = frameBody;
        }
        initMobileScroll_<%= this.ClientID %>('<%= scrollDiv.ClientID %>');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS devices you need set `overflow: auto;` or the scrolling won't work. For my web apps I used fancybox to display iframes modally and once I change the overflow setting in the css file the two finger scroll worked perfectly on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Would you check how it works with internal iframe(s) when Pane’s ContentUrl property is specified?

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/externalcontentloading/defaultcs.aspx